# How to update rows with many conditions in Dataframe, Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

How to update rows in DataFrame(Pyspark, not scala) where the update should happen on certain conditions? We dont know how many conditions will there be nor what they are during design time, so the conditions and the update values are to be applied at runtime.
Sample DataFrame.

Table T1:

```
| Emp_LName | Emp_FName     |  Sal          |   Sal_Grade  | 
| -------- | -------------- |-------------- |------------- |
| Smith    | Bob            |100000         |B             |
| Barnes   | Jim            |90000          |B             |
| Rogers   | Eric           |120000         |A             |
| Carson   | Ben            |45000          |C             |
```

```
df_source = spark.sql("Select * from T1)

lst_Conditions =[(Sal= 45000,Sal_Grade=E),(E_Name='Bob',E_Name='Robert),(One more candition),...].
```

(Basically the conditions are to be interpreted as 'Where Sal=45000, Then set Sal_Grade=E).

How do I write code for each condition to update the dataframe?
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you
R

Comment: How will the conditions be supplied? What you have now is not valid Python

Comment: Conditions are submitted via a shell script to spark submit job as string, each condition enclosed in parenthesis, (Sal= 45000,Sal_Grade=E) , (Emp_FName='Bob', Emp_FName='Robert). The interpretation is "When Sal=45000, then update Sal_grade to E" , "When Emp_FName=Bob then update Emp_FName=Robert.

Answer (score 2):

```
df_source = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('Smith','Bob',100000,'B')
    ,('Barnes','Jim',90000,'B')
    ,('Rogers','Eric',120000,'A')
    ,('Carson','Ben',45000,'C')
  ], ['Emp_LName','Emp_FName','Sal','Sal_Grade']
)
                                           
lst_Conditions = [
    ('Cond_1', 'CASE WHEN Sal = 45000 THEN "E" END'),
    ('Cond_2', 'CASE WHEN Emp_FName = "Bob" THEN "V" END')
]

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_source = df_source.withColumn('coalesce', F.lit(None))

for c in lst_Conditions:
    df_source = df_source\
                          .withColumn(c[0], F.expr(c[1]))\
                          .withColumn('coalesce', F.coalesce('coalesce', F.col(c[0])))
                        


df_source\
          .withColumn('Sal_Grade', 
                      F.when(F.col('coalesce').isNull(), F.col('Sal_Grade')).otherwise(F.col('coalesce')))\
          .select('Emp_LName','Emp_FName','Sal','Sal_Grade')\
          .show()    


# +---------+---------+------+---------+
# |Emp_LName|Emp_FName|   Sal|Sal_Grade|
# +---------+---------+------+---------+
# |    Smith|      Bob|100000|        V|
# |   Barnes|      Jim| 90000|        B|
# |   Rogers|     Eric|120000|        A|
# |   Carson|      Ben| 45000|        E|
# +---------+---------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So we need to convert the condition list as in above. However I cannot have the additional Cond_1,Cond_2 columns. How do I update Sal_Grade to 'E' and Emp_FName Bob to 'V'?

Comment: What do you mean by update those columns? Please be more precise

Comment: The goal is to update Sal_Grade Column, When Sal=45000 then SAL_Grade =E.   
But as per your example Col(Cond_1)=E  where Sal is 45000.  
  
|   Carson|      Ben| 45000|        C|     E|  null|
+---------+---------+------+---------+------+------+

Comment: Edited the answer to update Sal_Grade column